# Fuzzy search doesn't find Márton when searching for Marton

Tags: sql, oracle

I have an **Oracle database** table which stores persons. E.g.:

```
|-------------|---------|
| Name        | Data    |
|-------------|---------|
| Marton      | XYZ     |
| Márton      | XYZ     |
|-------------|---------|
```

I do a fuzzy search with Oracle on the `name` column. The problem is when I search for `Márton` I get 2 entries (which is fine), but when I search for `Marton` I only get one entry which is not what I would expect.

Here is a complete example of what I try to do:

```
CREATE TABLE persons  (
    NAME VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL,
    DATA VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO persons VALUES('Marton', '42');
INSERT INTO persons VALUES('Márton', '42');

begin
    --ctx_ddl.drop_preference('my_store');
    ctx_ddl.create_preference('my_store', 'MULTI_COLUMN_DATASTORE');
    ctx_ddl.set_attribute('my_store', 'columns', 'NAME');

    --ctx_ddl.drop_preference('my_lexer');
    ctx_ddl.create_preference('my_lexer', 'BASIC_LEXER');  
    ctx_ddl.set_attribute('my_lexer','index_stems','NONE');

    --ctx_ddl.drop_preference('my_wordlist');
    ctx_ddl.create_preference('my_wordlist', 'BASIC_WORDLIST'); 
    ctx_ddl.set_attribute('my_wordlist','fuzzy_match','GENERIC');
    ctx_ddl.set_attribute('my_wordlist','stemmer','NULL');
end;
/

--DROP INDEX MY_FUZZY_IDX;
CREATE INDEX MY_FUZZY_IDX ON persons(NAME) INDEXTYPE IS CTXSYS.CONTEXT PARAMETERS ('datastore my_store section group ctxsys.auto_section_group lexer my_lexer wordlist my_wordlist stoplist ctxsys.empty_stoplist');

-- Returns only 1 entry! Not OK! 
select * from persons where contains(NAME, '(fuzzy(Marton, 65, 100, W) within NAME)', 0) > 0;

-- Returns both entries! OK!
select * from persons where contains(NAME, '(fuzzy(Márton, 65, 100, W) within NAME)', 0) > 0;
```

Am I build the index wrong or do I use the fuzzy search wrong?

Comment: Check this out http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/text.112/e24435/search.htm#CCAPP9536

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for my problem today. The `BASIC_LEXER` has an option called `base_letter` which is `NO` by default. If you set it to `YES`, Oracle will convert all words to their base letters (so `á` will become `a`) and the fuzzy search works as expected.

```
CREATE TABLE persons  (
    NAME VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL,
    DATA VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO persons VALUES('Marton', '42');
INSERT INTO persons VALUES('Márton', '42');

begin
    --ctx_ddl.drop_preference('my_store');
    ctx_ddl.create_preference('my_store', 'MULTI_COLUMN_DATASTORE');
    ctx_ddl.set_attribute('my_store', 'columns', 'NAME');

    --ctx_ddl.drop_preference('my_lexer');
    ctx_ddl.create_preference('my_lexer', 'BASIC_LEXER');  
    ctx_ddl.set_attribute('my_lexer','index_stems','NONE');

    -- THE FIX!
    ctx_ddl.set_attribute('my_lexer','base_letter','YES'); 

    --ctx_ddl.drop_preference('my_wordlist');
    ctx_ddl.create_preference('my_wordlist', 'BASIC_WORDLIST'); 
    ctx_ddl.set_attribute('my_wordlist','fuzzy_match','GENERIC');
    ctx_ddl.set_attribute('my_wordlist','stemmer','NULL');
end;
/

--DROP INDEX MY_FUZZY_IDX;
CREATE INDEX MY_FUZZY_IDX ON persons(NAME) INDEXTYPE IS CTXSYS.CONTEXT PARAMETERS ('datastore my_store section group ctxsys.auto_section_group lexer my_lexer wordlist my_wordlist stoplist ctxsys.empty_stoplist');

-- Returns both entries! OK!
select * from persons where contains(NAME, '(fuzzy(Marton, 65, 100, W) within NAME)', 0) > 0;
select * from persons where contains(NAME, '(fuzzy(Márton, 65, 100, W) within NAME)', 0) > 0;
```

See https://web.stanford.edu/dept/itss/docs/oracle/10g/text.101/b10730/cdatadic.htm for more.